# Unable to change permissions and user:group of SMB mounted directory

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, chmod, chown

I have a trueNAS SMB mount to a Proxmox VM directory. The mount works fine however, in order for services to automatically move files from one part of the same directory to another, I need to remove root as the user:group. I'm able to set the higher folders to the user I want and set the permissions at `/media` all the way into that directory at `/media/data/media` however, inside media is all `root` -

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 uaaron uaaron 4096 Feb 15 23:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root      0 Feb 16 15:08 movies
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root      0 Feb 16 15:08 music
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root      0 Feb 16 15:08 tv
```

where this resides -

```
/media/data
➜  data ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 5 uaaron uaaron 4096 Feb 15 23:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 uaaron uaaron 4096 Feb 15 23:00 ..
drwxrwxrwx 5 uaaron uaaron 4096 Feb 15 23:03 media
drwxrwxrwx 5 uaaron uaaron 4096 Feb 16 03:22 torrents
drwxrwxrwx 5 uaaron uaaron 4096 Feb 15 23:04 usenet
```

I used  `sudo chown -R uaaron:uaaron media`  and  `sudo chmod -R 775 media`  to own this directory and did the same for all inside it but not able to for the 3 above which is where the SMB is mounted.

My `fstab` file is structured as such -

```
//<ip/share> /media/data/media/tv cifs credentials=/home/uaaron/.smbcredentials 0 0
//<ip/share> /media/data/media/music cifs credentials=/home/uaaron/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I've searched quite a bit all over the place and my googlefu as failed me.

Comment: So I was able to temporarily fix this by commenting out the mounts in fstab and the setting the permissions and user:group on the folders and the un-commenting the mount config in fstab. Though, when restarting the VM after this, the problem persists. This leads me to believe this may be a permissions issue within the TrueNAS share itself.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this issue you'll need additions permissions for the user - `~/.smbcredentials,uid=xxx,gid=xxx 0 0` where uid & gid sets local permissions for the directory mounted as SMB, removing root.